# Determinates and Adjugates

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Here is a question I don't understand why adjugate of B is multipled twice.

I understand all the other operations except when it comes to the adjugate, in questions like this.

[image: Question]

Answer (score 2):

$$Badj(B) = \det(B)I_n$$

$$\det(B)\det(adj(B))=\det(B)^n$$

$$\det(adj(B))=\det(B)^{n-1}$$

Here $n=3$, hence $\det(adj(B))=\det(B)^2$ for this question.